# Confusion about the derivation of the TD-Learning update rule

Tags: mathematical-statistics, gradient-descent, reinforcement-learning, sum, temporal-difference

I am currently trying to understand the paper "Learning to Predict by the Methods of Temporal Differences" by Sutton. 
I am stuck with the following step:
[image: From "Learning to Predict by the Methods of Temporal Differences" by Sutton, p. 14]

(From "Learning to Predict by the Methods of Temporal Differences" by Sutton, p. 14)
I do not understand why the equality should still hold after switching the indices k and t and changing the inner sum to go from the beginning to the current temporal difference k instead of running over all temporal differences from t to the end. How is this transformation possible and are there any special assumptions involved for this to hold?

Edit: If I get it right, in essence this is all about proving:
$\sum^m_{t=1}\sum^m_{k=t}f(k,t) = \sum^m_{k=1}\sum^k_{t=1}f(k,t)$

I would be grateful for hints on how to accomplish that

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I found a solution:
As the order of summation does not matter, we can write it in set-form:
$\sum^m_{t=1} ... = \sum_{t'} \forall t' \le m$

so

$\sum^m_{t=1}\sum^m_{k=t} f(k,t)=\sum_{t'}\sum_{k'}f(k,t)=\sum_{t',k'}f(k,t), \forall t' \le m, k' \ge t', k' \le m$

and

$\sum^m_{k=1}\sum^k_{t=1}f(k,t) = \sum_{k'}\sum_{t'}f(k,t)=\sum_{k',t'}f(k,t) \forall k' \le m, t' \le k'$

The sets that the sum is built over are equal because $k' \le m, t' \le k' \implies t' \le m$